# how to prevent un expected special symbols in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

In eclipse i am getting un expected special symbols.As shown in image.
What might be the problem.Thanks in advance....[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those symbols are the white spaces you have in your code, such as *space*, *tab*, *carriage-return*, etc.

Use the button **Show Whitespace Characters** to turn them off/on. You should see the button just under the main menus.

EDIT:
If you don't see that button, you might need to enable it first: Right-Click just under the menu bar and select **Customize Perspective...**, then open the category **Editor Presentation**, then select **Show Whitespace Characters**. You will now see the button just under the main menu.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on an empty space of the toolbar and select "Customize perspective". On the "Tool bar Visiblity" tab, check the box for "Editor Presentation -> Show Whitespace Characters" and close the dialog.

Use this button to show/hide the white space symbols.